# htaccess - redirect query string and remove it from URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I search many topic about htaccess but still not success.

I want when people type address:

```
http://domain.com/?q=filename1
http://domain.com/?q=filename2
...
```

It will auto redirect to:

```
http://domain.com/download/filename1.html
http://domain.com/download/filename2.html
...
```

I try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?q=(.*)$ /download/$1.html [L,R=301]
```

But it is not working. How can I fix this?

Comment: See this `htaccess redirect query string` https://helponnet.com/2019/06/21/how-to-redirect-a-url-with-query-string-apache-htaccess/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using this may be helpful:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=(.*)
RewriteRule ^q(.*) /download/%1.html [L,R=301]
```

**EDIT:**

Try this :)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) /download/%1.html? [L,R=301]
```

By using `?` query string will be removed ;)

Comment: Thanks Mehrnaz K. But it redirect to http://domain.com/download/filename1.html?q=filename1 and not exist

Comment: Please fix, If with ?q=filename1 it doesn't show content and says: The page isn't redirecting properly
      
      
      
      
      
        
        
          Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
        

        
        

  This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
    cookies.

Comment: Hi Mehrnaz K. New code is not working, it is still http://domain.com/?q=filename1 (not redirect). Please help

Comment: @LoveKen, sorry, this new one works well, please test it, thanks